# System register not defined webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

When im trying to run my react app i recieve `Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined` from browser. Probably there is some problem with imports but I don't know why. Here's the code that is throwing an error, basically it's the first line. Webpack version - 5.24.2

```
System.register(["react", "react-dom", "./App"], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var React, ReactDOM, App_1;
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (React_1) {
                React = React_1;
            },
            function (ReactDOM_1) {
                ReactDOM = ReactDOM_1;
            },
            function (App_1_1) {
                App_1 = App_1_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App_1.default, null), document.getElementById('root'));
        }
    };
});
```

## UPDATE 1:

After adding `libraryTarget: 'system'` to webpack config now i have same error in first line of webpack output file

```
System.register([], function(__WEBPACK_DYNAMIC_EXPORT__, __system_context__)
```

## UPDATE 2:

> Problem is solved.

I've changed module in `tsconfig.json` from `system` to `commonjs` after that compiler stops creating files based on system.js

Comment: Your webpack version !?

Comment: Version - 5.24.2

Comment: Good, need use like this: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#librarytarget-system

Comment: I've added libraryTarget: 'system' to my webpack config but problem still exist